# MySQL get all associated records where at least one record matches query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get this MySQL search query to work. I want it to return all users where either the firstName, lastName, email, or at least one secondaryEmail match the search string. A user can have many secondary emails.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`,
       `users`.`first_name` AS `firstName`,
       `users`.`last_name` AS `lastName`,
       `users`.`email`,
       `usersSecondaryEmails`.`id` AS `usersSecondaryEmails.id`,
       `usersSecondaryEmails`.`email` AS `usersSecondaryEmails.email`
FROM `Users` AS `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `UsersSecondaryEmails` AS `usersSecondaryEmails`
        ON `users`.`id` = `usersSecondaryEmails`.`user_id`
WHERE (`users`.`first_name` LIKE '%bob%'
        OR `users`.`last_name` LIKE '%bob%'
        OR `users`.`email` LIKE '%bob%'
        OR `usersSecondaryEmails`.`email` LIKE '%bob%');
```

This query returns successfully, however when there is only a matching secondary email, it ONLY returns that email, not ALL associated emails. How can I change this query to return ALL emails if it finds at least one secondary email? I know it most likely will have a subquery with EXISTS in it but I'm not too sure where I would put it.

EDIT: Users table has first_name, last_name, and email
UsersSecondaryEmails table has user_id and email

If a user has 2 secondary emails (the 'email' column on UsersSecondaryEmails), and at least one of them matches the search string, I expect to get ALL of their secondary emails back. As of right now, this only returns the matching email.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Table structures???  Sample input???  Expected output???  Here's a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT u.`id`, u.`first_name` AS `firstName`, u.`last_name` AS `lastName`, u.`email`,
       us.`id` AS `usersSecondaryEmails.id`,
       us.`email` AS `usersSecondaryEmails.email`
FROM `Users` u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     `UsersSecondaryEmails` us
     ON u.`id` = us.`user_id`
WHERE (u.`first_name` LIKE '%bob%' OR u.`last_name` LIKE '%bob%' OR u.`email` LIKE '%bob%') OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM `UsersSecondaryEmails` us2
              WHERE us2.user_id = us.user_id AND us2.`email` LIKE '%bob%'
             );
```

This assumes you want all second emails even when only the fields in `users` match.  If not, that could be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

A Subquery should do it

```
 SELECT 
       `users`.`id`,
       `users`.`first_name` AS `firstName`,
       `users`.`last_name` AS `lastName`,
       `users`.`email`,
       `usersSecondaryEmails`.`id` AS `usersSecondaryEmails.id`,
       `usersSecondaryEmails`.`email` AS `usersSecondaryEmails.email`
    FROM users users, UsersSecondaryEmails usersSecondaryEmails
    WHERE users.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM UsersSecondaryEmails)
    AND users.id = usersSecondaryEmails.user_id

    AND
    (
    `users`.`first_name` LIKE '%bob%'
    OR
    `users`.`last_name` LIKE '%bob%'
    OR
    `users`.`email` LIKE '%bob%'
    )
```

Comment: This works, but isn't it inefficient to search all emails where the email is like bob and then narrow it down by ones where the user_id matches? It should be the other way around

Comment: That would be great if you could

Comment: done.  You are correct in your comment.  I was not 100% on your original logic.  Fixed now.

Comment: Now it is returning 0 results when a secondary email matches

Comment: That would lead me to believe that nobody with the '%bob%' criteria has an id in users that matches the user_id in usersSecondaryEmails.

Comment: No because you completely removed the LIKE search from usersSecondaryEmails table. It needs to search all of the specified fields.

Comment: Try the query now

Comment: How does an answer with commas in the `from` clause get so many upvotes?

Comment: Probably because they understand the difference between SQL and MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

You should use a subquery fpor avoid the use of column related  to a left join table in where (this produce an inner join)

```
SELECT `users`.`id`,
       `users`.`first_name` AS `firstName`,
       `users`.`last_name` AS `lastName`,
       `users`.`email`,
       t.`email` AS `usersSecondaryEmails.email`
FROM `Users` AS `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN (       
    select `usersSecondaryEmails`.`user_id`,  `usersSecondaryEmails`.`email`
    from `UsersSecondaryEmails`
    where `usersSecondaryEmails`.`email` LIKE '%bob%') t on t.`user_id` = `users`.`id 
where (

    `users`.`first_name` LIKE '%bob%'
    OR `users`.`last_name` LIKE '%bob%'
    OR `users`.`email` LIKE '%bob%'
    )
```

Comment: I'm getting "unknown column 'usersSecondaryEmails.user_id' in field list" error

Comment: It didn't fix it. Where is the `t` variable coming from?

Comment: t is an alias for the subquery  ..anyway you should add  a proper data sample and the expected  result